# How to fix 'TypeError: failed to fetch' (Chrome) / 'NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.' (FireFox) in WSO2-AM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am setting up WSO2-AM and uploading an API's servicedefinition swagger.json but upon trying the service in WSO2-AM, I get the response in FireFox "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.". In Chrome its response is "TypeError: Unable to fetch".
The server is informationproxy.com and has SSL configured. Looks fine having a green lock in the urlbar with trusted certificate-chain. It does not certify for using the ip-number "https://209.182.203.81:9443/store/"

Question is: what makes WSO2 respond (in FireFox) with "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

The service does not seem to be the problem, since it works fine in editor.swagger.io.
The service also works fine directly called from curl to the external serviceprovider, returning a valid JSON with the data I expect:

```
curl -k -X GET "https://tieka.nl/webservices/address/luxembourg/v1/?postcode=8080&number=1" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

Also: all other api-services that I have tried to implement fail with the same error message.

There is a side-effect. The response to this curl is an encrypted payload:

```
curl -k -X GET "https://209.182.203.81:8243/webservices/address/luxembourg/v1/?postcode=8080&number=1" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer a1111111-1aa1-1111-aaaa-1111aaaa1111"

<ns:binary xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">PCFET0NUWVBFIEhUTUwgUFVCTElDICItLy9JRVRGLy9EVEQgSFRNTCAyLjAvL0VOIj4KPGh0bWw+PGhlYWQ+Cjx0aXRsZT4zMDEgTW92ZWQgUGVybWFuZW50bHk8L3RpdGxlPgo8L2hlYWQ+PGJvZHk+CjxoMT5Nb3ZlZCBQZXJtYW5lbnRseTwvaDE+CjxwPlRoZSBkb2N1bWVudCBoYXMgbW92ZWQgPGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGlla2Eubmw6ODAvd2Vic2VydmljZXMvYWRkcmVzcy9sdXhlbWJvdXJnL3YxLz9wb3N0Y29kZT04MDgwJmFtcDtudW1iZXI9MSI+aGVyZTwvYT4uPC9wPgo8aHI+CjxhZGRyZXNzPkFwYWNoZSBTZXJ2ZXIgYXQgd3d3LnRpZWthLm5sIFBvcnQgODA8L2FkZHJlc3M+CjwvYm9keT48L2h0bWw+Cg==</ns:binary>
```

Comment: Are you sending any custom headers to backend?

Comment: definitely the problem in certificate. it's good to create a custom CA certificate, generate certificate that is valid for your IP & hostname(s), sign it with CA. put signed certs into wso2am and import CA into your browser/other client  truststore.